# ASP.NET Core logging too verbose

Tags: c#, azure, logging, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble with configuration logging in ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebApi application. I successfuly achieved logging messages to Azure and inspecting them in Log stream, however these logs are too verbose. I don't want to have messages from category `Microsoft.AspNetCore` to be logged in **information level**. This is my logging section in `appsettings.json` file:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost": "Debug",
    "GameHub": "Information" 
   }
}
```

And my `Program` class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => { config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional:true, reloadOnChange:true); })
            .ConfigureLogging((ctx, logging) =>
                {
                    logging.AddConfiguration(ctx.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                });
}
```

It still logs messages from category `Microsoft.AspNetCore` in **information level**, instead of **debug level**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, of course, because you told it so: `"Default": "Debug",` You said, debug everything from Debug Level and higher, which is almost everything (the only higher debug Level is Trace iirc). You have to set it to `"Default": "Warning",` (because the next higher debugging level is Information)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As sellotape said, the loglevel set in .NET Core is the minimum level.

When you set `Debug`, it will log `Critical, Error, Warning, Information, Debug` levels. It will **not** log `Trace` (highest verbosity).

If you don't want `Information`, you set it to `Warning`, then you only get `Critical, Error, Warning` logged.

However, if you want `Critical, Error, Warning, Debug` without the Information, you can't do that directly with the `appsettings.json`.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => { ... })
            .ConfigureLogging((webhostContext, builder) => {
                builder.AddConfiguration(webhostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                .AddFilter<ConsoleLoggerProvider>(logLevel => logLevel!=LogLevel.Information)
                .AddConsole()
                .AddDebug();
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights();
}
```

The

```
// by strong typedProvider
.AddFilter<ConsoleLoggerProvider>(logLevel => logLevel!=LogLevel.Information)
// or by name
.AddFilter("Console", logLevel => logLevel != LogLevel.Information)
// or generic/global
.AddFilter(logLevel => logLevel != LogLevel.Information)
```

adds logging filter with one of three predicates (`Func<string, string, LogLevel, bool>`, `Func<string, LogLevel, bool>`, `Func<LogLevel, bool>`) as seen in the [ASP.NET Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#filter-functions):

> #### Filter functions
>
> A filter function is invoked for all providers and categories that don't have rules assigned to them by configuration or code. Code in the function has access to the provider type, category, and log level. For example:
>
> ```
> WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
>     .UseStartup<Startup>()
>     .ConfigureLogging(logBuilder =>
>     {
>         logBuilder.AddFilter((provider, category, logLevel) =>
>         {
>             if (provider == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLoggerProvider" && 
>                 category == "TodoApiSample.Controllers.TodoController")
>             {
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return true;
>         });
>     })
>     .Build();
> ```

Comment: That is comprehensive, can I have one question? How affects this "Level" in the App Service Logs menu for an App Service? As far I see, "Application Logging (filesystem)" overrides everyting and if I choose ie. Information as Level then I have all the information, without filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Information level is *above* (or below, depending on how you see it) Debug level, and hence *less* verbose. If you set it to Debug, you also get all of Information (and Warning, Error). I doubt you can change it in the standard Core logging.

---

For reference, the logging levels across most logging frameworks, from most to least verbose, are:

Verbose,
Debug,
Information,
Warning,
Error,
Fatal

(Some frameworks use slightly different naming, as Tseng correctly notes in the comments below, but the basic idea remains the same).

On some frameworks - e.g. log4net - you can set the maximum as well as minimum levels, but AFAIK with Core's inbuilt logging, you set minimum only, and hence get everything above that as well.

Comment: Exactly, I am aware of this fact. So on Azure portal in Diagnostics logs section of my application I set Application Logging "On" with log level "Information". Shouldn't I get everything above the "Information" level then? (which means Warning, Error, Fatal levels)

Comment: For .NET Core abstractions, it's `Trace, Debug, Information, Warning, Error, Critical`

Comment: That's correct, but in your question you have the default level set to Debug, and your override for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost` is to Debug as well (i.e. no effective difference). The logging you set for `GameHub` is Information, so logging entries generated _explicitly_ by classes whose namespace begins with that should show for Information and above only.

Comment: @Donios: When you want to log `Critical, Error, Warning, Information` you have to set `"Xxx" : "Information"`, not `Debug`, because Debug is more verbose. You can't exclude a "middlelevel" logging

Comment: Read: You can't have `Critical, Error, Warning, Debug` because Information is less verbose than Debug. When you chose Debug, you will also get `Information`. If you want to exclude `Information` but get `Debug` you will have to write your own logging provider (or configure that in the external Logging library if you use one). Well technically you can with filters, but its not as pretty

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I understand it now :)